# i want to make file upload component in angular 7,there are expree.js,http client, what would be the better way to start my research?

Tags: angular7, angular-file-upload

I am doing my research to start preparing my file upload component.I need guidance which way it would be better, Using `Express.js` or `HTTP Client`,Or are there any other ways where i can achieve file upload component in angular 7

Comment: Hi Sai, are you allowed to like use 3rd party packages? If so, here are some good dependencies that might help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload & https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

Comment: _what would be the better way to start my research?_ Time, your interest towards learning new things, a computer connected to internet.